# How to know will nuget package work on .NET Core?

Tags: nuget, .net-core

I would expect some kind of filter to exists on website or in console.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't easy right now, unfortunately. There's an [issue open on the NuGet Github](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/3098) about adding a filter to the website.

Right now, the best way to tell if a package will work with .NET Core is by examining the frameworks it supports in the Dependencies section.

If **.NETStandard** is listed, the package supports .NET Core via the [.NET Platform Standard](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md):

[image: package supporting .NETStandard 1.0]

If a package's Dependencies section doesn't mention .NETStandard, or the Dependencies section is completely empty, it does not support .NET Core:

[image: package with empty Dependencies section]

Comment: I don't get why having no dependencies means that package doesn't support .NET Core?

Comment: @Vukoje The UI is a little confusing and should be updated IMO. No dependencies means something like "it supports the .NET Framework without any extra required packages". Since .NET Standard will be listed as a dependency target, that's currently the easiest way to tell if it supports .NET Core.

Comment: NuGet packages which include a PCL also support .NET Core, but will not show up in the list suggested above. Unfortunately, it is often difficult to spot which libraries ship a PCL from the summary on nuget.org. Additionally, nuget will require that you include an "imports" statement in your project.json to use a package built for a PCL profile.

Comment: This is wrong. If you look up RestSharp 106.6.9 in Nuget Package Manager, you wont see any dependencies, but if you open the package in Nuget package explorer, youll see that .NETStandard 2.0 is supported.

Comment: @bech When I look at https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/ it does list ".NETStandard 2.0" under the Dependencies section. Maybe my answer is worded in a confusing way?

Answer (score 1):

[image]Setup a .NET Core project in the version you want.  I keep 1.1 and 2.0 projects around for futzing with this.  Then try and add the nuget to the project.

For instance, ASPOSE will NOT add to a 1.1 project, but will add to a 2.0 project.

Easiest route in the short term until they fix this somehow.

Obviously this is no guarantee it still works but gives you a good idea if its api compat.