# Search for .NET Core or Standard NuGet packages

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm using Visual Studio Code on Mac OS X to develop .NET Core web APIs. I already understand that adding NuGet references [is done manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/packages) in the *project.json* file.

However, I'm not quite sure how to search NuGet for .NET Core specific libraries. The [Mac OS X tutorial in the .NET Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/using-on-macos) only instructs the developer to add project dependencies, and it doesn't go into detail about how the developer would know / discover the dependency names.

Is there a way to search NuGet specifically for .NET Core libraries, and/or libraries that are compatible with [.NET Standard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/)? I would like to use the Mac OS X terminal or even VSCode to do this. However, any solution would be a great starting point.

ps. I did come across [Reverse Package Search](https://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/), but I have no idea who created it, how up-to-date it is, and if it will be available six months from now.

Comment: Please vote for the feature request at https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/3098

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now (as of January 2017), there's no easy way to search unfortunately. It's an [open issue](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/3098) on the NuGet Github project.

The closest you can get right now is to look at the package dependencies *after* you find it (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098643/3191599)). That doesn't help you find it in the first place, though. It's currently a manual "educated guess" process.